# Is this the right way to use for loop

Tags: algorithm

Is this the right way to use for loop in order to find the sequence of $x_n$

```
x[0] = 0;
T[x_] := Piecewise[{{1 - x, 0 <= x < 1/7}, {(x + 6)/7, 
     1/7 <= x <= 1}}];
a[n_] := n/(n + 1);
b[n_] := n/(n + 5);
x[n_] := (1 - a[n - 1]) x[n - 1] + 
   a[n - 1]*T[(1 - b[n - 1]) x[n - 1] + b[n - 1] T[x[n - 1]]];
For[n = 1, n < 20, n++, Print[x[n]]];
```

Comment: The classic _Mathematica_ function for this is `Table`. In your case you might replace the For-loop with `Table[x[n] // N, {n, 20}]`.

Comment: See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18396#18396) and [this Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica).

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[x];

x[0] = 0;

T[x_] := Piecewise[{{1 - x, 0 <= x < 1/7}, {(x + 6)/7, 1/7 <= x <= 1}}];

a[n_] := n/(n + 1);

b[n_] := n/(n + 5);
```

Include memorization ([Functions That Remember Values They Have Found](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)) in the definition of `x` for effciency

```
x[n_] := x[n] = (1 - a[n - 1]) x[n - 1] + 
    a[n - 1]*T[(1 - b[n - 1]) x[n - 1] + b[n - 1] T[x[n - 1]]];
```

A `For` loop is inefficient. Use `Map (/@)`

```
N[x /@ Range[20]]

(*  {0., 0.440476, 0.773254, 0.926828, 0.980189, 0.99535, 0.999033, 0.999819, 
0.999969, 0.999995, 0.999999, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}  *)
```